# Tidy local git branches (best practice)

Tags: git, azure-devops

How to tidy local git branches after remote repo merge (approved pull request)

New to Git for a script project I have.  I want to know how to tidy my local branches after I've pushed branch feature1 which has been pull requested and approved (thus merged into master) on the remote repo.

```
git checkout -b feature1
```

make changes....

```
git add *
git commit -m 'feature1 changes'
git push origin feature1
```

A pull request is then created, approved, merged into master and then deleted.  However, on my local repo I still have the feature1 branch which differs from my local master.  What is the best way to get back to a local master that is identical to remote?  What is the best way to do this?

I realise working this way itself isn't necessarily best practice but at this stage its theoretical for when I have dev, test branches etc.

Comment: i just do `git fetch --all --prune` every now and then

Comment: thanks but this doesn't delete local branch that has been deleted on remote

Comment: i think it does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I'm working on Azure Devops projects, I use `git fetch --prune` to purge deleted branches on remotes. 
Then I use `git branch -d` on deleted branch the previous command has listed.

Note : if you squash when you complete a pull request, you will have to use `git branch -D`

Comment: Thanks this seems best solution to check what has been deleted and then delete manually

Answer (score 0):

Once a branch is merged, there is no need to keep it, so you can delete it as follow:

```
git branch -d branchName # to delete the local branch
git push origin :branchName # to delete the branch on remote "origin"
```

Comment: Thanks, note quite what I was after however as remote branch has already been deleted after pull request approval.  Good to know though.

Comment: Ha, indeed, my bad I misread part of your question (that the remote branches were already deleted)

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
git remote prune origin
```

Now your local branch `feature1` will be deleted because the branch doesn't exist in the remote.

Comment: thanks but this doesn't delete local branch that has been deleted on remote

Comment: maybe your remote (azure devops) not called `origin`, you can check it with `git remote -v`.